# Finding a way to skip an iteration in a table

Tags: plotting, control-systems, cellular-automata

I am creating a project in Wolfram that models oil slicking using Cellular Automata. In my project I have a function called vonNeumann Neighborhood that takes in a radius and a length of a size of a 2d square grid.

It's a simple algorithm that goes through the grid and checks if the sum of the x and y values are equal to the radius, less than the radius or neither(meaning it is greater than radius).

If it is equal to the radius, then it  changes that cell to a certain shade of Gray. If the sum of the absolute values of x and y is greater than the radius, it should be filled in as 0(white).

But if the sum of the absolute values of x and y is less than radius, then it should do Nothing and move to the next cell. This is because if the sum of the absolute values of x and y are less than the radius, it should have already been coloured in. Therefore, as the iteration increases, the shade of gray of the cells that get coloured should get lighter(sort of like a real life oil spill but in an unrealistic situation).

For some reason when I use **Nothing**, it gives me the left half of the current and previous iteration of the oil spill and fills in everything else as white. Can someone explain to me why this is and how to fix it so that it shows the whole picture. (The resulting Array Plot is hard to explain with words so I suggest you use the code as below.)

I have used a Manipulate that uses an ArrayPlot to create the grid and goes through iterations from 0-9, so that you can visualise what it would look like.

```
vonNeumannNeighborhood[r_, m_] := 
Table[
    If[
      Abs[x] + Abs[y] == r, 
      GrayLevel[r/10], 
      If[
        Abs[x] + Abs[y] < r, Nothing, 0]
      ], 
    {x, -m, m}, {y, -m, m}
];

Manipulate[
 ArrayPlot[vonNeumannNeighborhood[n, 9], Mesh -> True, 
  PlotLabel -> r == n], {n, 0, 9, 1}]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `Nothing` doesn't skip an index, it replaces the list element with literally nothing, so the length of the list is changed. For example

```
vonNeumannNeighborhood[5, 9] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Also, the `vonNeumannNeighborhood` function doesn't know any previous values.

One possible method is to store the matrix in a variable `mat`, and give this matrix as an argument to the function.

```
m = 9;

vonNeumannNeighborhood2[r_, oldmat_] :=
  Table[
   If[
    Abs[x] + Abs[y] == r, GrayLevel[r/10], 
    If[Abs[x] + Abs[y] > r, 0,
     mat[[x + m + 1, y + m + 1]]]], {x, -m, m}, {y, -m, m}];

mat = PadRight[{{}}, {2 m + 1, 2 m + 1}];
Manipulate[
 ArrayPlot[mat = vonNeumannNeighborhood2[n, mat], Mesh -> True, 
  PlotLabel -> "r=" <> ToString[n]], {n, 0, m, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, it works as I want it to. Could you clarify on what: mat[[x + m + 1, y + m + 1]] does? And, do you have a Wolfram Community account so I can mention you in the credits of my project?

Comment: @Kopiaobia you're welcome. For each x,y in the `Table`, the `If` statement says: If `Abs[x] + Abs[y] ` is r, greylevel, else if > r, 0, else use the value that was already there in the matrix. The matrix indices start at 1, not -9, so the `x+m+1` converts x from the table index to the real matrix index. There are probably other/better ways to do it as well. I do not have a Wolfram Community account.

Answer (score 2):

It is because you are using `Nothing`. Is this what you wanted?

```
vonNeumannNeighborhood[r_,m_]:=
 Table[
    If[Abs[x]+Abs[y]==r,
       GrayLevel[r/10]
       ,
       If[Abs[x]+Abs[y]<r,
          GrayLevel[1]
           ,
          0
       ]
     ],
     {x,-m,m},{y,-m,m}
  ]
```

Now

```
ArrayPlot[vonNeumannNeighborhood[3, 3], Mesh -> True,  PlotLabel -> r == n]
```

gives

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Replacing `GrayLevel[1]` with `Nothing` like you had it gives instead

[image: Mathematica graphics]

To see why, it is because Nothing changes the length of each row. See this when using `Nothing`

```
vonNeumannNeighborhood[2,2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Compare to when using `GrayLevel[1]` instead of `Nothing`. Now each row length remains the same.

```
vonNeumannNeighborhood[2, 2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You see the effect now more clear.

Answer (score 2):

Built-in functions such as `Norm` and `CoordinateBoundsArray`can be used for this purpose. As an example:

```
Clear["Global`*"];
Manipulate[
 With[{pts = CoordinateBoundsArray[{{-r, r}, {-r, r}}]}, 
  Map[Norm[#, 1] &, 
     pts, {2}] /. {a_ /; a <= r :> GrayLevel[0.2], _?NumberQ -> 
      GrayLevel[1]} // ArrayPlot[#
     , DataRange -> {{-r, r}, {-r, r}}
     , Frame -> True
     , FrameTicks -> Automatic
     (*,FrameTicks\[Rule]{{Range[-r,r],Range[-r,r]},{Range[-r,r],
     Range[-r,r]}}*)
     , PlotLabel -> "r=" <> ToString@r
     , Mesh -> All
     , PlotRange -> All
     ] &
  ]
 , {{r, 3}, 0, 9, 1}
 , ContentSize -> {300, 300}
 ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
vonNeumannNeighborhood2[r_, m_] :=
  Table[
    With[
      {distance = ManhattanDistance[{0, 0}, {x, y}]},
      If[distance >= r, 0, Rescale[distance, {0, r}, {1, 0}]]],
  {x, -m, m}, {y, -m, m}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using **DiamondMatrix**:

```
n = 9;
```

> Generate a list of DiamondMatrix in range 0 to n.
> The default value of 1 is replaced with the iteration index in order
> to prepare for the different gray tones for each iteration.

```
dmx = DiamondMatrix[# , {2 n + 1, 2 n + 1}] /. 1 -> (# + 1) & /@ Range[0, n];
```

[image]

> Function c is used for "aggregation" during the folding operation.
> The function is basically calculating the minimum out of every 2
> corresponding elements of the adjacent matrices, excepting the cases
> where one of the elements is 0. In that case it will return the 2/x
> where x is the non-zero element.

```
c[0, 0] := 0; c[0, x_] := 2/x; c[x_, 0] := 2/x; c[x_, y_] := Min[x, y];
```

> The folding part is sequentially "adding up" the dmx matrices using the custom defined function c for aggregation.

```
res = FoldList[ MapThread[ MapThread[c, {#1, #2}] &,  {#1, #2}] &, dmx];

Manipulate[ArrayPlot[res[[i]], Mesh -> True], {i, 1, n, 1}]

(* Output *)
```

[image]

Comment: Could you explain what this code means because I'm having trouble understanding it.

Comment: @Kopiaobia Please see the comments in code. I would kindly suggest you to check Wolfram Documentation for `DiamondMatrix`, `FoldList`, `MapThread` and so on... Fell free to ask if you have any other questions.